# How to make Postgresql Hstore work with rails 4 on ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, pg, hstore

So I read a few articles that I found in google how to make hstore make with Rails 4, and as it happens, it wasnt that easily as it was told so I decided to describe the steps that I had to take to make it work on UBUNTU machine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps to activate and use Hstore:

1) You need to create a migration with something like this:

```
def change
  enable_extension "hstore"
end
```

2) As it was for me, I had to install the thing called

> postgresql-contrib

on my ubuntu machine, which I did with apt-get command. Perhaps you may need to add a version of your postgresql to the end of the packet name, like this:

> postgresql-contrib-9.3

3) Now you can add migrations that add "hstore" fields to the tables, notice that these migrations should be following after the one that activates Hstore

4) Before u run the migrations, you might have to change to the root user of your DB and give the user that u use to access the db (most likely used in the database.yml file) an allowance to add this kind of columns, I did it with the following commands:

> sudo -u postgres psql

(where postgres is the root user of the db )

and in the command line of the database write:

> alter user [rails account name] with superuser;

5) Run the migrations

6) Change the user allowance back to the way it was with the following command:

> alter user [rails account name] with nosuperuser;

That's it, now u should be able to use the hstore...

PS I am a bit of a newbie so perhaps I made some mistakes or something, but I hope its all fine :)